# Get all images with specific SRC value on web page, using vbscript

Tags: image, web-scraping, vbscript, scripting

I have a HTML like below

```
<img src="a.gif" height="12" width="12">
<img src="a.gif" height="12" width="12">
<img src="a.gif" height="12" width="12">
<img src="b.gif" height="12" width="12">
<img src="b.gif" height="12" width="12">
```

I need to count no.of img tags with src="a.gif" using vbscript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim a
a=0

For Each pix In objIE.document.images
   If pix.src= "full image path (eg:https://www.google.com/a.gif)" then
       a=a+1
    End if
Next
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

I would use

```
objIE.document.querySelectorAll("[src='a.gif']").Length
```

This is the fastest way to get count of only a specific set of srcs by their values. No need for a loop. It uses css attribute=value selector to match on the relevant nodes and the .Length property of the returned nodeList to get the item count.